# Interface and abstract class in this case

Tags: c#, oop

In case I want any class inherits/implements some methods which is better an interface or an abstract class contains these abstract methods only and acts as an interface. I know the difference between the interface and the abstract class well but in this case do the two have the same function or there are different something?

I think we can feel free to use one of them but still I take the side of interface because my aim is to enforce any class to implement these methods and it is the job of interface.

Comment: Interfaces and abstract classes are very different things.  It's not really clear what you're asking or what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I take the side of the interface as well. I salute you, brother! Sounds like you just answered your own question: Use what fits the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree an abstract class with no concrete behavior seems a little pointless so I would favour an interface.

Abstract classes are far more useful when bringing together some common behavior that cannot be overridden along with some elements that can eg) template methods

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        AbstractMethod1();
        AbstractMethod2();
    }

    public abstract void AbstractMethod1();
    public abstract void AbstractMethod2();
}


public class Concrete : Base
{
    public override void AbstractMethod1()
    {
        Console.Write("Override Abstract Method 1");
    }

    public override void AbstractMethod2()
    {
        Console.Write("Override Abstract Method 2");
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        var concrete = new Concrete();
        concrete.TemplateMethod();
    }
}
```